# 信用度スコアの title 属性に 10,000 未満の信用度が反映されていない

Tags: バグ

### 不具合事象

信用度スコアの `title` 属性に 10,000 未満の信用度が反映されておらず、何も書かれていません。また、これは信用度が書かれているほとんどの箇所で再現します。

以下の画像は、[ユーザー一覧](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)の suzukis さんと mjy さんのユーザー情報の HTML です。各ユーザーで画像の赤線部を見比べると、一方は `title` 属性に信用度が書かれていますが、もう一方では書かれていないことが確認出来ます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

### 関連投稿

Meta Stack Exchange にて同様の投稿がありました。

- [Trailing space on reputation score tooltip - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217897)

Answer (score 3):

信用度が 10,000 を超えているユーザーの場合、プロフィールカードの表示では **1万** (英語版では **10k**) のように数値が丸められているので、title 属性でマウスオーバーした際に正確な数値が表示されるよう設定されているのだと思います。
(1万未満の場合には既に正確な数値が表示されているため、title 属性は省略されているのだと思われます)

こちらは現状、英語版でも同じ仕様のようです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！信用度が省略されている理由について、確かにあり得そうだと感じました。英語版では末尾にスペースが付いているだけで、あまり目立ちませんが、日本語版ではコロンを用いているため、違和感が増している気がします。ja.traducir.win に当該文字列があれば、コロンをスペースに差し替えようかと考えています。

Comment: 場合によっては「信用度が10k未満の場合はツールチップを表示しない」などの修正案も考えられるので、もう少し様子を見てからでもいいのかなと思います。